# Prevent other admin users from changing network settings, ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking

On an Ubuntu linux server, I would like to prevent other root users / admins from changing the network settings. I want to set a static IP address/network settings and then lock it in a way that even other admins cannot change it.

Is there a way? How can I do this?

Thank you...

Comment: are they root just like you or normal users ? if they are root i am afraid there is nothing you can do on the other hand if they are normal users there is a few possible things.

Comment: they are also root admin users

Comment: If you can't trust them not to fiddle with stuff like this then they shouldn't have root access, period.

Comment: there you have a good point Robert, however I am still interested to know if there is a technical solution :) or if it is just impossible

Comment: There inst, if they are root they have the same level of access within the server as you do, if they have enough knowledge they can simply switch back any changes you may do to restrict them. but if they are normal users then they would be limited to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on the answers above.

This fellow used SELinux to secure a machine with public root access as a proof of concept.
SELinux - http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6836
However, SELinux is an adventure to learn.

You could use the `chattr +i` above and just not tell them about it...depending on how clever your users are. `chattr -i` would allow any root user to edit the file. In addition `+a` allows only appending.

The "normal" way to do this would be to create normal users and specifically give them the privleges they should have via something like the free tool `Sudo`.

Comment: additionally to +i , +a for some critical confs such as /etc* try to set +u (keep a backup of the file if it's deleted).

But this solution works only if you use ext* filesystem. If you use something else, i don't think that is being supported.

Comment: -2 is unnecessary. If anything the SE Linux root security link is original and 100% relevant to OP. Would also be nice if the downvoters would comment and let me know what it was voted down for, so I could address the issue in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider chattr +i, maybe in combination with lcap, but I will have to research this further.

Answer (score 1):

Do they have access to the machine ? If no, then it's easy. 
If yes, then you could create a **seperate group** .. let's say superadmin and the only person in that group will be you.

How are they taking root priviledges ? Login ? sudo ? Without being totally sure,  i think that **SELINUX** can help you assign **priviledges** based on the **source ip**.

Answer (score 0):

if these users are root, then no. However it should be possible to have layered administration using sudo and pam authentication levels using normal user accounts to perform the tasks needed day-to-day.

To avoid simple mistakes etc, you may find setting the configuration files immutable (chattr +i) may help.